# Delay task dependent multiple asynchronous MongoDB queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to pull arrays from multiple collections from my MongoDB database. The initial code assumes the arrays 'links' & 'sites' are substantiated. I would prefer to collect this array data elsewhere in my mongoDB database and draw from it when needed. My initial assumption was that I could collect from the database, before calling render...

```
// connect to database.
mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((result) => app.listen(5000))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))

// create database object.
const db = mongoose.connection;

// render the page.
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('links').find({...})
     .then((result) => {
         res.render('index', { title: "Home", result, sites })
     })
     .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
     })
});
```

The issue with this attempt is that I can only draw from one collection. I believe this is a good guarantee that I will not have issues waiting for the asynchronous tasks between MongoDB and my app, but I would like to know another way that I can guarantee that the information is there from separate collections before I continue. As an example of the incorrect way, I would do:

```
// connect to database.
mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((result) => app.listen(5000))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))

// create database object.
const db = mongoose.connection;
const links_res = db.collection('links').find({...})
const sites_res = db.collection('sites').find({...})

// render the page.
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('index', { title: "Home", links_res, sites_res })
});
```

I do not think there is any guarantee that the information is accessible when render is called. How should I guarantee that?

Comment: `Promise.all()` will let you get notified when multiple promise-based DB queries have completed if that's what you're trying to do.  You don't actually show code that doesn't work so it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've made changes to further define response goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `db.collection('links').find({ ...})` gives you a promise, not a database result.  You have to `await` or `.then()` that promise to get the actual result.

You can use `Promise.all()` like this:

```
const links_p = db.collection('links').find({ ...})
const sites_p = db.collection('sites').find({ ...})

// render the page.
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [links_res, sites_res] = await Promise.all([links_p, sites_p]);
        res.render('index', { title: "Home", links_res, sites_res})
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Note, you also need to fix your `res.render()` call which was not passing arguments correctly.  The 2nd argument to `res.render()` should be an object with properties.  You pass multiple pieces of data by creating multiple properties on that object.

Since most incoming requests will arrive long after those two promises are resolved, the `Promise.all()` will typically be instant so you don't really need to worry about the fact that you're always waiting on the promise.

But, a possible problem with this code is that the db query is static. The query is done once at server startup and never again updated.  And, if you ever get an error on those initial queries, you aren't really handling it well.

Comment: What is the purpose of the async keyword in the function declaration? Is this so crucial?

Comment: @TheShanachie - You can only use `await` inside an `async` function.  This code uses `await`, thus the containing function must be declared `async`.

Comment: This is very interesting! If I wanted to pass an array of objects to the render call, is that possible? @jfriend00

Comment: @TheShanachie - Yeah, you need to fix your `res.render()` call.  I'd sugges this: `res.render('index', { title: "Home", links_res, sites_res})` and then you need to change the template to match how you're passing the data.  Any property value can be an array if you want.

Comment: I think this would be very helpful if I understood the type value is our .collections(...).find(...) is returning. Also I believe this will be an additional question so I will wait some time and then post another when Stack Overflow allows next. May I use your example above? @jfriend00

Comment: As of the moment, I believe we are passing some non-array type as an argument to res.render(). As far as I understand.

Comment: @TheShanachie - Yeah, you've really wandered into another question about how to properly use `res.render()` with multiple arguments and perhaps in understanindg how `.find()` works and those would be best discussed in a new question.  I think we've successfully dealt with the original asynchronous question.

Comment: I understand it may be against SO guidelines, but I am not able to ask questions and this has been an issue for months. Currently, I am executing the query listed above in each time the app needs to handle a request. Would someone be able to ask a question and link it here? I would like to know if it's possible to query once since the data never changes, then cache the query results as global variables at the beginning of the program?

Comment: @TheShanachie - Why can't you post your own question?

Comment: I think I've had a number of bad questions which the community didn't like

Comment: I'm also not sure if there are other forums for a question like this @jfriend00

Comment: @TheShanachie - Well, please don't try to circumvent those posting restrictions by asking your own question in comments.

Comment: I understand. My apologies. @jfriend00